# Error on retrieve Hive Table on Orange Data Mining - Hive Table Widget

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, hive, orange

I'm trying to read `hive table` via **Hive Table widget** on `Orange Data Mining`, but i get this error:

```
Could not create 'Hive Table'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyspark\sql\utils.py", line 63, in deco
    return f(*a, **kw)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\py4j\protocol.py", line 328, in get_return_value
    format(target_id, ".", name), value)
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o38.sql.
: org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient;
```

> What I've installed:

```
Orange Data Mining 
PySpark
Anaconda3
A Bitnami Hadoop instance
```

Comment: If all you did was install Anaconda and Pyspark, it doesn't include Hive packages

Comment: I've installed Hive package, and it still failed. I think it's due to the OS compatibility, i traced the entire error message and i found this line:
 `code`java.lang.RuntimeException: Error while running command to get file permissions : java.io.IOException: (null) entry in command string: null ls -F C:\tmp\hive

Will try it on linux though

Comment: What does this have to do with Orange? From what I know, there is no Hive Table widget.

Comment: If you're on Windows, you must add `winutils.exe` to your PATH. But installing Hive is not necessary. Compiling Spark with Hive support is what I meant (assuming you already have a Hive server running elsewhere, which Bitnami has https://docs.bitnami.com/general/apps/hadoop/)

Comment: If you download Spark from their website, it'll have Hive and Hadoop support. Alternatively, if all you want is to use Hive, you can use Pandas+Pyhive

Comment: @vijolica Perhaps https://github.com/jamartinh/Orange3-Spark (which I point out to @ Irfan that it says to download Spark from the website, not just PySpark)

Comment: Oh, I see. This is not an officially supported add-on, so I think the best to write to the author, namely the add-ons issue tracker.

Comment: vijolica sorry i forgot to mention that i use Orange3-Spark as mentioned by cricket_007. I still havent try it on linux, nor the suggestions from cricket_007. Will update it here once it's succeed. Thanks for the responses.